# Doctrine2: ManyToMany not delivering the right lists

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a university class entity, and a student (user) entity. A User can be member of many classes, and classes can have many students. (Manytomany)

I created the many to many, and it seems to persist fine. I can get the users of the class ( `$class->getUsers()`) but `$user->getClasses()` does not seem to work. (important: my entity is called `Classes`, since PHP complains about the name `Class` being reserved )

this is from my User Entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Confidence\ClassBundle\Entity\Classes", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_classes",
 * joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 * inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="classes_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $classes;
.
.
.
.
public function __construct() 
{
    $this->classes = new ArrayCollection();
}
 .
 .
 .
 .
 .
/**
 * Get classes
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getClasses()
{
    return $this->classes;
}
```

and this is from the classes entity

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Confidence\UserBundle\Entity\User", mappedBy="classes")
 */
protected $users;
.
.
.


function __construct()
{
    $this->users    = new ArrayCollection();
}
.
.
.
.
/**
 * Get classes
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}
```

This is the symfony2 controller part, where the persistance is done

```
......
        unset($classArray['product_ids']);
        $class = new Classes();
        $class->fromArray($classArray);
        $loggedInUser->addClasses($class);
        $class->addUser($loggedInUser);
        $em->persist($loggedInUser);
        $em->persist($class);

        foreach ($productIds as $product) {
            $prod = $productRepo->find($product);
            if ($prod === null) {
                throw new \Confidence\CoreBundle\Exception\NotFoundException();
            }
            $prod->addClasses($class);
            $em->persist($prod);
        }
        $em->flush();
        return $class;
......
```

And this is the part where i do the var_dump or i run xdebug watchpoint

```
    /* @var $user \Confidence\UserBundle\Entity\User */
    $user    = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('ConfidenceUserBundle:User')->find($this->getSession()->getUserId());

    $classes = $user->getClasses();
    var_dump($classes);die();
```

And here is a `var_dump` of the `$user->getClasses()`, which is basically empty

```
object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[268]
  private 'snapshot' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
  private 'owner' => 
    object(Confidence\UserBundle\Entity\User)[259]
      protected 'id' => int 39533
      protected 'token' => null
      protected 'tokenExpiration' => null
      protected 'canvasId' => int 6870
      protected 'oauthToken' => string 'fTn2CCK7BY4uaUN6h71q78xRwnn0Cx43T3JgxBjRNJMBBu4LpvHLRvkRmuUrJ5md' (length=64)
      protected 'classes' => 
        &object(Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection)[268]
      protected 'lastLogin' => int 0
      protected 'systemTime' => int 1375694342
      protected 'products' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      protected 'dtoType' => null
  private 'association' => 
    array (size=19)
      'fieldName' => string 'classes' (length=7)
      'joinTable' => 
        array (size=4)
          'name' => string 'users_classes' (length=13)
          'schema' => null
          'joinColumns' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          'inverseJoinColumns' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
      'targetEntity' => string 'Confidence\ClassBundle\Entity\Classes' (length=31)
      'mappedBy' => null
      'inversedBy' => string 'users' (length=5)
      'cascade' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      'orphanRemoval' => boolean false
      'fetch' => int 2
      'type' => int 8
      'isOwningSide' => boolean true
      'sourceEntity' => string 'Confidence\UserBundle\Entity\User' (length=27)
      'isCascadeRemove' => boolean false
      'isCascadePersist' => boolean false
      'isCascadeRefresh' => boolean false
      'isCascadeMerge' => boolean false
      'isCascadeDetach' => boolean false
      'joinTableColumns' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'user_id' (length=7)
          1 => string 'classes_id' (length=10)
      'relationToSourceKeyColumns' => 
        array (size=1)
          'user_id' => string 'id' (length=2)
      'relationToTargetKeyColumns' => 
        array (size=1)
          'classes_id' => string 'id' (length=2)
  private 'em' => 
    object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[132]
      private 'config' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Configuration)[116]
          protected '_attributes' => 
            array (size=12)
              ...
      private 'conn' => 
        object(Doctrine\DBAL\Connection)[129]
          protected '_conn' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection)[249]
              ...
          protected '_config' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration)[126]
              ...
          protected '_eventManager' => 
            object(Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ContainerAwareEventManager)[127]
              ...
          protected '_expr' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Query\Expression\ExpressionBuilder)[130]
              ...
          private '_isConnected' => boolean true
          private '_transactionNestingLevel' => int 0
          private '_transactionIsolationLevel' => int 2
          private '_nestTransactionsWithSavepoints' => null
          private '_params' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
          protected '_platform' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform)[131]
              ...
          protected '_schemaManager' => null
          protected '_driver' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver)[128]
              ...
          private '_isRollbackOnly' => boolean false
          private '_defaultFetchMode' => int 2
      private 'metadataFactory' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory)[133]
          private 'em' => 
            &object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[132]
          private 'targetPlatform' => 
            object(Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\MySqlPlatform)[131]
              ...
          private 'driver' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\DriverChain)[221]
              ...
          private 'evm' => 
            object(Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ContainerAwareEventManager)[127]
              ...
          protected 'cacheSalt' => string '$CLASSMETADATA' (length=14)
          private 'cacheDriver' (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory) => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache)[117]
              ...
          private 'loadedMetadata' (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory) => 
            array (size=3)
              ...
          protected 'initialized' => boolean true
          private 'reflectionService' (Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\AbstractClassMetadataFactory) => 
            object(Doctrine\Common\Persistence\Mapping\RuntimeReflectionService)[137]
              ...
      private 'repositories' => 
        array (size=1)
          'ConfidenceUserBundle:User' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository)[108]
              ...
      private 'unitOfWork' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork)[134]
          private 'identityMap' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          private 'entityIdentifiers' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          private 'originalEntityData' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          private 'entityChangeSets' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'entityStates' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          private 'scheduledForDirtyCheck' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'entityInsertions' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'entityUpdates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'extraUpdates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'entityDeletions' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'collectionDeletions' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'collectionUpdates' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'visitedCollections' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            &object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[132]
          private 'commitOrderCalculator' => null
          private 'persisters' => 
            array (size=1)
              ...
          private 'collectionPersisters' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'evm' => 
            object(Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ContainerAwareEventManager)[127]
              ...
          private 'orphanRemovals' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'readOnlyObjects' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'eagerLoadingEntities' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      private 'eventManager' => 
        object(Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\ContainerAwareEventManager)[127]
          private 'listeners' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'initialized' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'container' => 
            object(appProdProjectContainer)[28]
              ...
          private '_listeners' (Doctrine\Common\EventManager) => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      private 'hydrators' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      private 'proxyFactory' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory)[135]
          private '_em' => 
            &object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[132]
          private '_autoGenerate' => boolean false
          private '_proxyNamespace' => string 'Proxies' (length=7)
          private '_proxyDir' => string '/opt/arran/jura-backend/app/cache/prod/doctrine/orm/Proxies' (length=59)
      private 'expressionBuilder' => null
      private 'closed' => boolean false
      private 'filterCollection' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Query\FilterCollection)[255]
          private 'config' => 
            object(Doctrine\ORM\Configuration)[116]
              ...
          private 'em' => 
            &object(Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager)[132]
          private 'enabledFilters' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
          private 'filterHash' => null
          private 'filtersState' => int 1
  private 'backRefFieldName' => string 'users' (length=5)
  private 'typeClass' => 
    object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)[260]
      public 'name' => string 'Confidence\ClassBundle\Entity\Classes' (length=31)
      public 'namespace' => string 'Confidence\ClassBundle\Entity' (length=23)
      public 'rootEntityName' => string 'Confidence\ClassBundle\Entity\Classes' (length=31)
      public 'customGeneratorDefinition' => null
      public 'customRepositoryClassName' => null
      public 'isMappedSuperclass' => boolean false
      public 'parentClasses' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'subClasses' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'namedQueries' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'namedNativeQueries' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'sqlResultSetMappings' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'identifier' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'id' (length=2)
      public 'inheritanceType' => int 1
      public 'generatorType' => int 4
      public 'fieldMappings' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          'password' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
          'publicDescription' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
          'created' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          'startAt' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          'endAt' => 
            array (size=9)
              ...
          'name' => 
            array (size=8)
              ...
      public 'fieldNames' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string 'id' (length=2)
          'password' => string 'password' (length=8)
          'publicDescription' => string 'publicDescription' (length=17)
          'created' => string 'created' (length=7)
          'startAt' => string 'startAt' (length=7)
          'endAt' => string 'endAt' (length=5)
          'name' => string 'name' (length=4)
      public 'columnNames' => 
        array (size=7)
          'id' => string 'id' (length=2)
          'password' => string 'password' (length=8)
          'publicDescription' => string 'publicDescription' (length=17)
          'created' => string 'created' (length=7)
          'startAt' => string 'startAt' (length=7)
          'endAt' => string 'endAt' (length=5)
          'name' => string 'name' (length=4)
      public 'discriminatorValue' => null
      public 'discriminatorMap' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'discriminatorColumn' => null
      public 'table' => 
        array (size=2)
          'name' => string 'classes' (length=7)
          'options' => 
            array (size=0)
              ...
      public 'lifecycleCallbacks' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
      public 'associationMappings' => 
        array (size=2)
          'products' => 
            array (size=16)
              ...
          'users' => 
            array (size=16)
              ...
      public 'isIdentifierComposite' => boolean false
      public 'containsForeignIdentifier' => boolean false
      public 'idGenerator' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Id\IdentityGenerator)[277]
          private '_seqName' => null
      public 'sequenceGeneratorDefinition' => null
      public 'tableGeneratorDefinition' => null
      public 'changeTrackingPolicy' => int 1
      public 'isVersioned' => null
      public 'versionField' => null
      public 'reflClass' => 
        object(ReflectionClass)[267]
          public 'name' => string 'Confidence\ClassBundle\Entity\Classes' (length=31)
      public 'isReadOnly' => boolean false
      protected 'namingStrategy' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultNamingStrategy)[124]
      public 'reflFields' => 
        array (size=9)
          'id' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[276]
              ...
          'password' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[261]
              ...
          'publicDescription' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[275]
              ...
          'created' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[274]
              ...
          'startAt' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[273]
              ...
          'endAt' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[272]
              ...
          'name' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[271]
              ...
          'products' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[270]
              ...
          'users' => 
            object(ReflectionProperty)[269]
              ...
      private '_prototype' (Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataInfo) => null
  private 'isDirty' => boolean false
  private 'initialized' => boolean false
  private 'coll' => 
    object(Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection)[266]
      private '_elements' => 
        array (size=0)
          empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that classes are not loaded from the database when fetching the user (because you don't use a join). Doctrine will try to do another query to fetch the classes. But ONLY if you do something with these classes, like reading properties from them or filtering them. It's best if you try to make a join so you do just 1 query instead of 2.